# Proof verification: For any ordinals $\gamma,\beta$, $\gamma\le \gamma+\beta$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I need to prove that for any ordinals $\gamma,\beta$, $\gamma\le \gamma+\beta$.

Proof by induction:

Base case: when $\beta=0, \gamma+\beta=\gamma+0=\alpha$ 
Thus $\gamma=\gamma+ \beta\le \gamma+\beta$.

Step case: Assume that for an ordinal $\beta$ we have $\gamma\le \gamma+\beta$, then for $\beta^+$, we have:

$\gamma\le \gamma+\beta$

$<  \gamma+\beta\cup \lbrace  \gamma+\beta\rbrace$

$=(\gamma+\beta)^+$

$=\gamma+\beta^+ $

Hence by induction, for any ordinals $\gamma,\beta, \gamma\le \gamma+\beta.$

Could someone please tell me if I am correct? Thanks!

Comment: The statement involves quantification over both $\gamma$ and $\beta$.  You have not provided an induction over $\gamma$.  You also need to do the limit case for $\beta$

Comment: Sorry I have not learnt how exactly can I deal with that. May I please ask for a proof?

Comment: @RossMillikan The question is about ordinal numbers. May I please ask if there is some difference from the definition of **Ordinal numbers** to **Ordinals**

Comment: ajax and I are both assuming your ordinal numbers include infinite ones.  You induction breaks down if $\beta$ is a limit ordinal, as it is not then a successor.  Then I don't know what justification you have for the last equality.  Maybe you have that as a theorem, in which case you are fine.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes I see, the last equality is the definition of ordinal addition in my text.

Comment: Then you are OK for successor $\beta$ but have not dealt with limit $\beta$

Comment: @RossMillikan I am trying to do induction on $\gamma$, where I am a little stuck, may I please ask for some explaination for induction on $\gamma$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57567/discussion-between-ross-millikan-and-non-abelian-group-of-order-9).

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do ordinary induction, you want to do transfinite induction. In that case, your induction step requires checking on successor ordinals (which you've done) and for limit ordinals (those $\beta$ which do not have any $\beta' < \beta$ such that $(\beta')^+ = \beta$ (in your notation).

Comment: Sorry I do not know how exactly can I deal with it, may I please ask for a proof?

Comment: After searching my textbook I cannot find an example of transfinite induction. Could you please show me how to do that?